# Compiled regex performance not as expected?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm looking over Joe Albahari's C# 5.0 in A Nutshell and in Chapter 26 regarding regular expressions, he states:

> In some of the proceeding examples, we called a static `RegEx` method repeatedly with the same pattern. An alternative approach in these cases is to instantiate a `Regex` object with the pattern and then call instance methods . . .

```
// Code example from the book
Regex r = new Regex (@"sausages?");
Console.WriteLine (r.Match ("sausage"));   // sausage
Console.WriteLine (r.Match ("sausages"));  // sausages
```

> This is not just a syntactic convenience: under the covers . . . This results in (up to 10 times) faster matching, at the expense of a small initial compilation cost (a few tens of microseconds).

So the curious me wrote a benchmark. This program splits a string, iterating ~ 32 million calls of both the static calls and instance calls of `Regex`, as well as an alternative way to perform the same task.

```
class Program {
  static void Main(string[] args) {
    var str = "01/02/03/04/05/06/07/08/09/10";
    var regex = new Regex("/");
    var results = new List<Tuple<string, long>>();

    for (int j = 0; j < 128; j++) {
      var s = Stopwatch.StartNew();
      for (var i = 0; i < 1024 * 1024; i++) {
        RegexSplit(str);
      }
      s.Stop();
      results.Add(new Tuple<string, long>("Regex", s.ElapsedTicks));

      s = Stopwatch.StartNew();
      for (var i = 0; i < 1024 * 1024; i++) {
        CompiledRegexSplit(str, regex);
      }
      s.Stop();
      results.Add(new Tuple<string, long>("Compiled", s.ElapsedTicks));

      s = Stopwatch.StartNew();
      for (var i = 0; i < 1024 * 1024; i++) {
        StringSplit(str);
      }
      s.Stop();
      results.Add(new Tuple<string, long>("String", s.ElapsedTicks));

      Console.Write(".");
    }

    var resultsGroup = from it in results
      group it by it.Item1
      into g
      select new {
        Type = g.Key,
        Avg = g.Average(git => git.Item2)
      };

    resultsGroup.ToList().ForEach(it => Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1:000000000.00}", it.Type, it.Avg));
  }

  static void StringSplit(string str) {
    var split = str.Split('/');
  }

  static void CompiledRegexSplit(string str, Regex regex) {
    var split = regex.Split(str);
  }

  static void RegexSplit(string str) {
    var split = Regex.Split(str, "/");
  }
}
```

and got the following results:

```
Regex:    12257601.40
Compiled: 10869996.92
String:   01328636.27
```

That's not quite what I expected based on the book, and I doubt that instantiating one `Regex` takes 12 million ticks.

This run was in .NET 4.5, x64 release mode.

What is the explanation of the unexpected result?

Comment: By compile, he probably meant `RegexOptions.Compiled`. 
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);

Comment: Your regex is NOT compiled! `var regex = new Regex("/");`

Comment: Compiled in terms of RegEx is indeed including the compiled flag in the constructor.

Comment: @Bidou His code example lists `Regex r = new Regex (@"sausages?")` - updated question

Comment: @Bidou Nevermind http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=0636920023951

Comment: @Bidou I think you should add this comment as answer, with explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has only produced an instance of a Regex object.  To use an actual compiled Regex object, you must specify the RegexOptions.Compiled option.  This will inform the Regex object that it will be used in such a way that it is worth the up front cost to compile itself so that it can be executed more quickly.

The reason it is not done automatically is that for a limited number of runs, the process of compiling the regular expression will actually take longer than the time saved.  The Regex object exists to hold a regular expression with meta data such as Regex engine options and such, so it may be used with or without compilation.

The code to do the compilation would be:

```
var regex = new Regex("/", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```